# ASP.NET Core MVC (Piranha CMS) not finding views and home when published

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, piranha-cms

I've got a web app based on Piranha CMS. It is debugging fine, but when I publish the app, it won't work.

Index returns 404 and no log entry in the console or event log, if I call any of my custom controllers, the view is not being found.

All I did was install the .NET 8 runtime on my development machine; no changes were made to my project.

The issue is present on my dev machine as well as my production server. Running the backed-up published version works on both machines.

Seems like MS broke my publish chain in the background...

Can somebody please help me? :D

Answer (score 0):

After fiddeling around, cleaning the solution, re-pulling it from git etc. the only fix that worked was adding the follonwing lines to the csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish><CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Can anybody explain why this was neccessary?